# is it possible to show the verbose info when using docker pull

Tags: docker

Now I am using docker pull to fetch some image:

```
docker pull python:3.10-alpine3.16
```

I tried to config some registry mirror but I did not know the pull process using the mirror or not. is it possible to make the docker show verbose info? or any other way to show the mirror info when using docker pull command? I have already tried:

```
docker pull --verbose python:3.10-alpine3.16
```

I also read the docker pull --help, but found no detail about the verbose output.